# struts2 validation framework doesn't work in client side

Tags: validation, struts2, client-side

I am using the struts2 validation framework to validate the data from in client.
I have read a lot of validation framework tutorials but still cannot not find where i make the mistake.

I use Struts 2.2.3. The struts.xml configuration as following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.1//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.1.dtd">
<struts>
  <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />

  <package name="admin" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
    <default-action-ref name="index" />

    <global-results>
      <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
    </global-results>

    <global-exception-mappings>
      <exception-mapping exception="java.lang.Exception" result="error" />
    </global-exception-mappings>

    <action name="login" class="com.text.LoginAction">
      <result name="login">/login_page.jsp</result>
      <result name="success">/login_success.jsp</result>
      <result name="error">/login_page.jsp</result>
    </action>
  </package>
</struts>
```

In the index.jsp, i go struts2 action and enter login page.

```
<body>
  <a href="login!handle.action">Go to Login Page</a>
</body>
```

login_page.jsp

```
<body>
  <s:form action="login!login.action" validate="true" method="post">
    <s:textfield name="username" label="Username"/>
    <s:textfield name="password" label="Password"/>
    <s:submit value="Submit"/>
  </s:form>
</body>
```

LoginAction, @SkipValidation annotation is used to skip the validation for specific method

```
public class LoginAction extends ActionSupport {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String username;
    private String password;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String login() {
        if (username.equalsIgnoreCase("root") && password.equalsIgnoreCase("1234")) {
            return "success";
        } else {
            return "fail";
        }
    }

    @SkipValidation
    public String handle() {
        return "login";
    }
}
```

LoginAction-validation.xml in the same package with LoginAction.

```
<!DOCTYPE validators PUBLIC "-//OpenSymphony Group//XWork Validator 1.0.2//EN"
     "http://www.opensymphony.com/xwork/xwork-validator-1.0.2.dtd">

<validators>
  <field name="username">  
    <field-validator type="requiredstring">
      <param name="trim">true</param>
      <message>Login name is required</message>  
    </field-validator>
  </field>

  <field name="password">
    <field-validator type="requiredstring">
      <param name="trim">true</param>
      <message>Password is required</message>
    </field-validator>
  </field>  
</validators>
```

After adding the validate="true" in s:form, i go to the page and try to access validation.js and utils.js. They turn out to be the apache tomcat error report file. I think it means the client side validation doesn't work. Can anyone help me to fix it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What does your filter mapping look like?

Comment: I just add the strut2 StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter and map to .action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By mapping to .action, instead of the wildcard as documented in the [S2 web.xml docs](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/webxml.html) you prevent S2 from serving the required JavaScript files.

You may extract the static files S2 normally serves itself, or correct your mapping.

Comment: I got your idea. But in this web application, i also need to add web serivice using jersey. If i use wildcard, the request from web service will be filter by struts2. Do you have any idea to figure it out?

Comment: The second sentence of my answer, also detailed in the page I linked to.

Comment: You can also exclude certain paths from the `StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter`, allowing you to run JAX-RS and Struts2 together.